Azure Pipelines - Setup Bitbucket Cloud service connection with basic auth
Setup Bitbucket Cloud service connection with basic auth
I would like to set up a Bitbucket Cloud service connection with basic authentication, but the verification fails all the time. I even tested it with an app password, which had all the permissions. How could I diagnose?

Hi @XtonicChen, Have you got a chance to test verification with your Bitbucket username instead of the email as suggested in the answer below? Hope it may resolve your issue in this post. Appreciate your time and sharing.

You had probably been using the user email + App Password for verification. Please use the user account name instead of the user email and try again. I managed to create the Bitbucket Cloud service connection this way.



